# Auto Generate JS variables if data in array exists PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a map on my site that has plots placed on it using data from my table. The plots are placed with javascript as so...

```
addPostCode('<?php echo $array[$UID][0]; ?>');
addPostCode('<?php echo $array[$UID][1]; ?>');
addPostCode('<?php echo $array[$UID][2]; ?>');
```

Somehow I need to see if the variable exists in my table, and then if so, generate an additional line and increment my array number, so based on the above 3 records, the next line would be...

```
addPostCode('<?php echo $array[$UID][4]; ?>');
```

Can I ask if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop through all of the members of the `$array[$UID]` variable.

```
<?php
    foreach($array[$UID] as $thing) {
        $encodedThing = json_encode($thing);
        echo "addPostCode($encodedThing);\n"
    }
?>
```

I used `json_encode()` because it does whatever escaping is necessary to make your data JavaScript-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, this is what you would do:

```
addPostCode('<?php $i=0; while (isset( $array[$UID][$i])) { echo $array[$UID][$i]; $i++ ; } ?>');
```

That would replace all your `addPostCode()` calls also.